# How Do I fix the Swift Sort function error?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a Swift1 book, but I have Xcode 7. So I am coding Swift2 based on a Swift1 book.  I'm currently learning Swift closure, but the following code produces an error.

```
import Cocoa

let names = ["Chris","Alex","Ewa","Barry","Daniella"]

func backwards(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {
    return s1 > s2
}

print("Unsort names: \(names)")

var reversed = sort(names, backwards)
print("sort names: \(reversed)")
```

This is the error:

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/kt/t3wp7ckx3h1c33tfm44r4zgr0000gn/T/./lldb/1968/playground150.swift:11:16: 
error: cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '([String], (String, s2: String) -> Bool)'
var reversed = sort(names, backwards)
               ^
/var/folders/kt/t3wp7ckx3h1c33tfm44r4zgr0000gn/T/./lldb/1968/playground150.swift:11:16: 
note: overloads for 'sort' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (inout C, (C.Generator.Element, C.Generator.Element) -> Bool), (inout [T], (T, T) -> Bool), (inout ContiguousArray<T>, (T, T) -> Bool)
var reversed = sort(names, backwards)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply sort function to an array object

```
var reversed = names.sort(backwards)
```

Below is the screenshot of my playground

[image]

Comment: Thank You! I help very much!